# Jquery Mobile 2 ListView inside Tab issue

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am having issues or i should say the whole list breaks if i use the following code

```
<div data-role="content" class="ui-content-menu">
            <div data-role="tabs">
                <div id="one" class="tablist-content">
                    <h1>APPETIZER</h1>
                    <ul data-role="listview">
                       <li><a href="acura.html">Acura</a></li>
                       <li><a href="audi.html">Audi</a></li>
                       <li><a href="bmw.html">BMW</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div id="two" class="tablist-content">
                    <h1>Second tab contents</h1>
                </div>
                <div id="three" class="tablist-content">
                    <h1>third tab contents</h1>
                </div>
                 <div id="four" class="tablist-content">
                    <h1>First tab contents</h1>
                </div>
                <div id="five" class="tablist-content">
                    <h1>Second tab contents</h1>
                </div>
                <div id="six" class="tablist-content">
                    <h1>third tab contents</h1>
                </div>
                 <div id="seven" class="tablist-content">
                    <h1>First tab contents</h1>
                </div>
                <div id="eight" class="tablist-content">
                    <h1>Second tab contents</h1>
                </div>


                 <ul data-role="listview" class="tablist-right" data-icon="false">
                  <li><a href="#one"><div><img alt="Appetizers" src="images/Icons/Ic_Appetizer_54.png"/><h3 class="cat-heading">APPETIZER</h3></div></a></li>
                  <li><a href="#two"><div><img alt="Main Course" src="images/Icons/Ic_MainCourse_54.png"/><h2 class="cat-heading">MAIN</h2></div></a></li>
                  <li><a href="#three"><div><img alt="Sides" src="images/Icons/Ic_Sides_54.png"/><h2 class="cat-heading">SIDES</h2></div></a></li>
                  <li><a href="#four"><div><img alt="Dessert" src="images/Icons/Ic_Desserts_54.png"/><h2 class="cat-heading">DESSERT</h2></div></a></li>
                  <li><a href="#five"><div><img alt="Set Meals" src="images/Icons/Ic_SetMeals_54.png"/><h2 class="cat-heading">SET MEALS</h2></div></a></li>
                  <li><a href="#six"><div><img alt="Drinks" src="images/Icons/Ic_Drinks_54.png"/><h2 class="cat-heading">DRINKS</h2></div></a></li>
                  <li><a href="#seven"><div><img alt="Alcohol" src="images/Icons/Ic_Alcohol_54.png"/><h2 class="cat-heading">ALCOHOL</h2></div></a></li>
                  <li><a href="#eight"><div><img alt="Coffee" src="images/Icons/Ic_Coffee_54.png"/><h2 class="cat-heading">COFFEE</h2></div></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

What i currently want to achive is a list inside tab- that tab is itself buit using data-role="list-view" as you can see. if i remove list code from the appetizer section it works great.

Thank in advance for any help.

Comment: Are you not using the jQM tabs widget? It uses a data-role="navbar" for the list: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/tabs/

Comment: see if this works for you http://jsfiddle.net/toct7x0u/1/

Comment: Thanks @AtanuCSE this worked, i actually couldn't get what is the difference?

Comment: The problem was in the order of the segment. Somehow JQM gets confused when you're ordering tab segment before the list segment. I'm posting it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem may be in the ordering of the segments. I don't know why is it behaving like this, but putting tab segment in the end works. http://jsfiddle.net/toct7x0u/1/

```
 <div data-role="content" class="ui-content-menu">
        <div data-role="tabs" id="my_tabs">

             <ul data-role="listview" class="tablist-right" data-icon="false" id="listss">
              <li><a href="#one"><div><img alt="Appetizers" src="images/Icons/Ic_Appetizer_54.png"/><h3 class="cat-heading">APPETIZER</h3></div></a></li>
              <li><a href="#two"><div><img alt="Main Course" src="images/Icons/Ic_MainCourse_54.png"/><h2 class="cat-heading">MAIN</h2></div></a></li>
              <li><a href="#three"><div><img alt="Sides" src="images/Icons/Ic_Sides_54.png"/><h2 class="cat-heading">SIDES</h2></div></a></li>
              <li><a href="#four"><div><img alt="Dessert" src="images/Icons/Ic_Desserts_54.png"/><h2 class="cat-heading">DESSERT</h2></div></a></li>
              <li><a href="#five"><div><img alt="Set Meals" src="images/Icons/Ic_SetMeals_54.png"/><h2 class="cat-heading">SET MEALS</h2></div></a></li>
              <li><a href="#six"><div><img alt="Drinks" src="images/Icons/Ic_Drinks_54.png"/><h2 class="cat-heading">DRINKS</h2></div></a></li>
              <li><a href="#seven"><div><img alt="Alcohol" src="images/Icons/Ic_Alcohol_54.png"/><h2 class="cat-heading">ALCOHOL</h2></div></a></li>
              <li><a href="#eight"><div><img alt="Coffee" src="images/Icons/Ic_Coffee_54.png"/><h2 class="cat-heading">COFFEE</h2></div></a></li>
                 </ul>
            <div id="one" class="tablist-content">
                <h1>APPETIZER</h1>

                <ul data-role="listview" id="list" data-inset="true">
                   <li><a href="acura.html">Acura</a></li>
                   <li><a href="audi.html">Audi</a></li>
                   <li><a href="bmw.html">BMW</a></li>
                    </ul> 
            </div>
            <div id="two" class="tablist-content">
                <h1>Second tab contents</h1>
            </div>
            <div id="three" class="tablist-content">
                <h1>third tab contents</h1>
            </div>
             <div id="four" class="tablist-content">
                <h1>First tab contents</h1>
            </div>
            <div id="five" class="tablist-content">
                <h1>Second tab contents</h1>
            </div>
            <div id="six" class="tablist-content">
                <h1>third tab contents</h1>
            </div>
             <div id="seven" class="tablist-content">
                <h1>First tab contents</h1>
            </div>
            <div id="eight" class="tablist-content">
                <h1>Second tab contents</h1>
            </div>


        </div>
    </div>
```